# Como descobrir a operadora de um número de celular?

Tags: android

Preciso desenvolver um aplicativo para efetuar chamadas usando um chip de celular, mas para isto, tenho que saber a operadora do numero destino.

Tem como descobrir a operadora de destino, programaticamente, no android?

Comment: Cara, Quando for fazer uma pergunta coloque a linguagem que você deseja fazer isso.

Comment: TAG = Android é um Sistema Operacional da Google para dispositivos móveis. Utilize esta tag para referenciar perguntas relacionadas à programação para Android e seja relevante apenas para este sistema operacional. Use a tag escrevendo [android-assunto] ao invés de [assunto] isoladamente.

Comment: Entendo cara mas Android é um S.O, O ideal é usar a Tag Android junto a linguagem que deseja, porque eu poderia postar um código de inúmeras linguagems e não ser a que você deseja.

Comment: aqui tem um site que mostra como os numeros sao distribuidos https://www.teleco.com.br/num_cel.asp

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29):

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
String simOperatorName = manager.getSimOperatorName();
```

**Edição**

A operadora do número de destino via api do android é impossível, não tem como o Sistema Operacional saber a operadora baseado apenas no número, principalmente com a portabilidade. O que eu recomendaria seria pagar alguma empresa que possua esse Web Service e fazer uma requisição no seu app.
Fazendo uma pesquisa rápida encontrei esse [site](http://consultanumero.abrtelecom.com.br/consultanumero/consulta/consultaSituacaoAtualCtg)

Comment: Mas isto não me retorna a operadora destino, mas sim a operadora do chip que está no celular, ou estou errado?

Comment: @Valdomiro Editei minha resposta